# Downsample pandas data frame based on count column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a thousands of data frame like the following, though much larger (1000000 rows, 100 columns).

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'cols1':[4, 5, 5, 4, 321, 32, 5],
                     'count':[45, 66, 6, 6, 1, 432, 3],
                     'Value':['Apple', 'Boy', 'Car', 'Corn', 'Anne', 'Barnes', 'Bayesian']})
```

I want to randomly sample from this data frame and make a new data frame such that the sum of count should only equal N. Meaning I want to randomly sample based on the count value as a weight, and make a new data frame with this new resampled data such that sum of count is N.

The relative proportions should stay approximately the same, and no value when resampled should exceed the count of the original count value. The values in cols1 (or any other column except Value and count) should remain the same.

For example, if N was 50, it might look like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'cols1':[4, 5, 5, 4, 321, 32, 5],
                     'count':[4, 7, 1, 1, 0, 37, 0],
                     'Value':['Apple', 'Boy', 'Car', 'Corn', 'Anne', 'Barnes', 'Bayesian']})
```

How can this be done?

Efficiency is key, otherwise I could expand the data frame based on count and randomly sample without replacement, then merge it back together.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: the result of this operation does not change the shape of the data frame. Why not do `np.ceil(df.count * N / df.count.sum())`. The resulting `count` column keeps the same frequency distribution, but its sum may be off by a small whole number, which you can then randomly add / subtract from rows to equal `N`.

Comment: I like this idea, but I do not want to unintentionally add a bias that may skew downstream results. Therefore I would like to do random sampling without replacement, but with the count column specifying the max number of times a value can be sampled without calling it as using replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multinomial sampling, this is relatively easy.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

def downsample(df, N):
    prob = df['count']/sum(df['count'])
    df['count'] = list(chain.from_iterable(np.random.multinomial(n = N, pvals = prob, size = 1)))
    df = df[df['count'] != 0]
    return df
```

For OP's example:

```
downsample(data, 50)
```

returns:

```
    Value  cols1  count
1     Boy      5      1
3    Corn      4     16
5  Barnes     32     33
```

Comment: This solution leaves the possibility that a row/sample will be assigned a **higher** count than it had originally, which is a problem if the intent is to simulate a random selection of a subset of whatever items are being counted in the `count` column.